# Opportunities view - All with more than 50,000 opportunities

Tags: visualforce

I have a simple question - in SalesForce, if there are more than 50,000 opportunities and if a user selects "Opportunities - All" view, how many opportunities will be displayed? Is there no way for the user to go through all the opportunities in this case? For example, if there are 150,000 total opportunities and if the requirement is to let user go through all opportunities, how will I provide that functionality?

What are the suggested ways to handle this situation in salesforce?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, not really, without filtering. Besides the obvious part of there is no physical way for one person to review that much data individually, there are ways to handle this.

1. Filter the results to something more manageable.
2. Group the data into smaller result sets.
3. Export the data to a different database system that doesn't have that limitation.
4. Export the data to a local file for processing.
5. Use Batch Apex, which can handle millions of records, but only in small batches and asynchronously.

With a more concrete use case a more tailored solution can be created for your needs.

Comment: It wouldn't take more than a few days to navigate through 150,000 rows. Assume the user fears his or her job enough to perform the menial task of scrolling through 750 pages of opportunities.

Comment: And, I created over 50,000 records in my large demo org just to prove this point.

Answer (score 1):

For anything much larger than 10,000 rows of data, consider having the user run a report. Exporting the report to a spreadsheet is more economical time-wise for the user at that point.

That being said, standard list views do support navigating beyond 50,000 rows of data. The old list view mode had a parameter you could tweak to jump to a particular page (e.g. page 500 for the 100,000th record using 200 rows per page mode) as well as a maximum page size (hard capped at either 500 or 1000).

The new list view is JavaScript-based and also supports navigating beyond the 50,000th row of data (page 250 in 200 rows per page mode). However, it does not support jumping to the "last page" or entering an arbitrary page number to jump to until the entire size of the list is known, so navigation takes a significant amount of time unless you "hack" the list view with JavaScript of your own.

There's no need to do anything to "provide this functionality", since it is supported by the platform. However, if you're using Visualforce, then you must specifically program the page to use pseudo-offsetting. I usually perform this trick by sorting by a known field (e.g. CreatedDate), and limiting the result set. An example query would look like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, CloseDate FROM Opportunity WHERE CreatedDate > 2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 100
```

With this query, I can simply set the filter to the result from the last "page" of data, allowing perpetual scrolling far beyond the normal 50,000 query row limit, without using the "read-only" attributes or any intense JavaScript code. However, this part of the answer is purely informational, since the platform's native list views already support navigating between any number of pages.

Note that very large lists might time out if the user doesn't have permission to view all opportunities. Indeed, "all opportunities" is really "all opportunities for which I could physically access because I have permission to view." Administrators can always scroll through all the data.